# Se entiende como

Tags: significado

¿Hay otra forma de decir "se entienden" en la siguiente frase? No estoy seguro si se puede sustituir "se entienden" por "se sobreentiende". ¡Muchísimas gracias!

"[El Hotel París ... fue uno de los primeros hoteles en Madrid tal y como se entienden en la actualidad](https://es.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hotel_Par%C3%ADs)".

Comment: ¡Muchísimas gracias por las explicaciones de Ustedes!

Comment: Por favor no olvides marcar la respuesta como aceptada si tu problema se solucionó.

Comment: En singular, y no plural. Es pronominal.  Se entiende algo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El uso de "entender" no es el más adecuado en la oración:

"El Hotel París ... fue uno de los primeros hoteles en Madrid tal y como **se entienden** en la actualidad."

No hay nada que entender sobre los hoteles. Sí se puede usar con la preposición "por", pero no está presente en la oración: *Se entiende **por "hotel"** un establecimiento donde se pueden alojar turistas.*

Sería más correcto utilizar "conocer", porque no se refiere a la palabra "hotel" sino al concepto "hotel":

"El Hotel París ... fue uno de los primeros hoteles en Madrid tal y como **se conocen** en la actualidad."

o

"El Hotel París ... fue uno de los primeros hoteles en Madrid tal y como **se los conoce** en la actualidad."

Más allá de que sea entendible la oración con "entender" (valga la redundancia), la superioridad léxica de "conocer" puede observarse si confrontamos estas dos oraciones:

- Los establecimientos donde se alojan pasajeros **se entienden** como hoteles.
- Los establecimientos donde se alojan pasajeros **se conocen** como hoteles.

"Se entienden" y "se conocen" son formas pasivas. Si usamos la pasiva perifrástica, la opción con "entender" se vuelve, a mi criterio, agramatical:

- *Los establecimientos donde se alojan pasajeros **son entendidos** como hoteles.
- Los establecimientos donde se alojan pasajeros **son conocidos** como hoteles.

La misma diferencia se observa en este par de oraciones, donde claramente la opción correcta es aquella en la que se usa "conocer":

- ?A los establecimientos donde se alojan pasajeros **se los entiende** como hoteles.
- A los establecimientos donde se alojan pasajeros **se los conoce** como hoteles.

Comment: Creo que realizas una valoración subjetiva cuando dices "no hay nada que entender sobre los hoteles". Para mí la oración es correcta y perfectamente comprensible, y es que está queriendo decir que la idea moderna que tenemos de "hotel" no era la misma hace tiempo; por tanto, el concepto "hotel" significaba algo ligeramente distinto, aunque solamente fuera por connotaciones

Comment: @FGSUZ Es una cuestión gramatical. Los hoteles se conocen, no se entienden. El sustantivo "hotel" no puede ser objeto del transitivo "entender".

Comment: Efectivamente, los hoteles se conocen, pero "el concepto de hotel" se puede entender de distintas formas, y parece ser que lo que todo el mundo entiende por "hotel" ha debido de cambiar, aunque sea ligeramente, a lo largo de las décadas

Comment: @FGSUZ Con tu comentario me has dado el pie. Dices: lo que todo el mundo entiende POR "hotel". En la oración original, no está ese "por", y eso hace que "conocer" suene mejor que "entender" porque "conocer" acepta el objeto "hoteles" directamente, sin mediar una preposición.

Comment: Bueno, el tema de las preposiciones es un mundo. En español no tenemos palabras como "en"/"y" en francés para sustituir un sintagma preposicional. La cuestión es que, aunque te suene mejor "conocer", se ha de admitir que la oración del enunciado es perfectamente correcta

Answer (score 2):

A las anteriores respuestas añadiría "tal y como se conciben en la actualidad".

Answer (score -1):

Desde mi punto de vista habría varios modos de expresar la locución, pero ninguno de esos modos incluyen la palabra "sobreentender", pues sobreentender o sobrentender, esta última la preferida, "*se refiere a entender algo que no está expreso*" y en este contexto, utilizar esta palabra no es la más adecuada.

- "*El Hotel París ... fue uno de los primeros hoteles en Madrid tal y como se entienden en la actualidad*".
- "*El Hotel París ... fue uno de los primeros hoteles en Madrid tal y como se **interpretan** en la actualidad*".
- "*El Hotel París ... fue uno de los primeros hoteles en Madrid tal y como se **perciben** en la actualidad*".
- "*El Hotel París ... fue uno de los primeros hoteles en Madrid tal y como **el concepto se comprende** en la actualidad*".
- "*El Hotel París ... fue uno de los primeros hoteles en Madrid tal y como se **advierten** en la actualidad*".
- "*El Hotel París ... fue uno de los primeros hoteles en Madrid tal y como se **ven** en la actualidad*".